# Does CString member function CompareNoCase support other language (non-English)?

Tags: c++, string, windows, mfc, compare

I am working in Windows,using vc++2010 and MFC, in Unicode.

Following is my code:

```
CStringW strLowerGreek(L"αβγ");
CStringW strUpperGreek(L"ΑΒΓ");

if (0 == strLowerGreek.CompareNoCase(strUpperGreek))
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Two strings are the same"));
else
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Two strings are different"));
```

When I run the code, pop-up message is "Two strings are different".

**What I wanna do** is to create αβγ.txt in C disk  and ΑΒΓ.txt in D disk for example(I can't create αβγ.txt and ΑΒΓ.txt in the same disk), I think αβγ.txt and ΑΒΓ.txt have the same name(not the full path,just file name), then I wanna compare the two files contents, and check them if the same.So I need a function to compare the two files name ingoring case-sensitivity.

My question are:

1. According to the pop-up message, `CString` member function `CompareNoCase` don't support Greek lower case and upper case. So is there something  can do the work in MFC or in C++?
2. Is there function or library support non-English (such as Greek, Russian) upper case and lower case comparison. I wanna ingore the case sensitivity when comparing two strings.

Comment: [__This__](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314315.aspx) and [__this__](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx) should help.

Comment: Actually, since NTFS is case-sensitive, you *can* create both "αβγ.txt" and "ΑΒΓ.txt" in the same directory. You'd have to pass `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` to a call to [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx). I'm not sure, this is a good idea, or how file managers like *Explorer* behave when confronted with files whose names differ in case only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is set the **locale**. Example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
CStringW strLowerGreek(L"αβγ");
CStringW strUpperGreek(L"ΑΒΓ");
int i = strLowerGreek.CompareNoCase(strUpperGreek);
CStringW strText;
strText.Format(L"%s %s %d", strLowerGreek, strUpperGreek, i);
AfxMessageBox(strText);

CStringW strLowerGreek2 = strLowerGreek.MakeUpper();
i = strLowerGreek2.CompareNoCase(strUpperGreek);
strText.Format(L"%s %s %d", strLowerGreek2, strUpperGreek, i);
AfxMessageBox(strText);
```

I have used the [setlocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale) to set the locale. Initially I set it to the Greek (`"ell"`) locale, but any locale other than the C locale works. So the more generic `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` can be used to set the current locale equal to the system locale.

When I leave it with the **default locale** (which is *English*):

- The return value is `32`.
- The text is **not converted** to **UPPERCASE**.

When I set the locale first to **Greek**:

- The return value is `0`.
- The text *is converted* to **UPPERCASE**.

---

Result of `CompareNoCase`:

[image: Result of CompareNocase]

Result of `MakeUpper`:

[image: Result of MakeUpper]

---

I thought setting the locale only affected things like **date formatting**. But it also affects **string comparisons**. See the `_wcsicmp` reference: [Call setlocale with any locale other than the C locale before the call to _wcsicmp.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l) for additional information.

Comment: @zett42 Updated the example to use `CStringW` and `L""`. But the user might not want the system locale. If the program is running in English, but they want to test Greek text, they might have to be specific?

Comment: @zett42 Confirmed at my end too. I have incorporated your comment into the answer and adjusted my code.

Comment: While this answers the question that was asked, it doesn't solve the issue the OP was having (but never explained). The code would need to follow the collation rules of the underlying file system to reliably produce the lower- or upper-case versions of a file name. I'm no expert on the topic, but I believe that NTFS supports multiple collation rules, too.

Comment: Ignore that, collation and casing are not the same thing. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")  maybe explicit?

Comment: @zet Personally my application supports 46 languages and needs to format dates. So in my case I set the locale according to the language the user has chosen. Use what suits your situation.